# Linear regression poor gradient descent performance

Tags: c++, algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, linear-regression

I have implemented a simple Linear Regression (single variate for now) example in C++ to help me get my head around the concepts. I'm pretty sure that the key algorithm is right but my performance is terrible.

This is the method which actually performs the gradient descent:

```
void LinearRegression::BatchGradientDescent(std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> & data,float& theta1,float& theta2)
{

    float weight = (1.0f/static_cast<float>(data.size()));
    float theta1Res = 0.0f;
    float theta2Res = 0.0f;

    for(auto p: data)
    {

        float cost = Hypothesis(p.first,theta1,theta2) - p.second;
        theta1Res += cost;
        theta2Res += cost*p.first;
    }   

    theta1 = theta1 - (m_LearningRate*weight* theta1Res);
    theta2 = theta2 - (m_LearningRate*weight* theta2Res);
}
```

With the other key functions given as:

```
float LinearRegression::Hypothesis(float x,float theta1,float theta2) const
{
    return theta1 + x*theta2;
}


float LinearRegression::CostFunction(std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> & data,
                                     float theta1,
                                     float theta2) const
{ 
    float error = 0.0f;
    for(auto p: data)
    {

        float prediction = (Hypothesis(p.first,theta1,theta2) - p.second) ;
        error += prediction*prediction;
    }

    error *= 1.0f/(data.size()*2.0f);
    return error;
}

void LinearRegression::Regress(std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> & data)
{
    for(unsigned int itr = 0; itr < MAX_ITERATIONS; ++itr)
    {
       BatchGradientDescent(data,m_Theta1,m_Theta2);
       //Some visualisation code
    }
}
```

Now the issue is that if the learning rate is greater than around 0.000001 the value of the cost function *after* gradient descent is higher than it is *before*. That is to say, the algorithm is working in reverse. The line forms into a straight line through the origin pretty quickly but then takes ***millions*** of iterations to actually reach a reasonably well fit line.

With a learning rate of 0.01, after six iterations the output is: (where difference is costAfter-costBefore)

```
Cost before 102901.945312, cost after 517539430400.000000, difference 517539332096.000000
Cost before 517539430400.000000, cost after 3131945127824588800.000000, difference 3131944578068774912.000000
Cost before 3131945127824588800.000000, cost after 18953312418560698826620928.000000, difference 18953308959796185006080000.000000
Cost before 18953312418560698826620928.000000, cost after 114697949347691988409089177681920.000000, difference 114697930004878874575022382383104.000000
Cost before 114697949347691988409089177681920.000000, cost after inf, difference inf
Cost before inf, cost after inf, difference nan
```

In this example the thetas are set to zero, the learning rate to 0.000001, and there are 8,000,000 iterations! The visualisation code only updates the graph after every 100,000 iterations.

[image]

Function which creates the data points:

```
static void SetupRegressionData(std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> & data)
{
    srand (time(NULL));

    for(int x = 50; x < 750; x += 3)
    {
        data.push_back(std::pair<int,int>(x+(rand() % 100), 400 + (rand() % 100) ));
    }
}
```

In short, if my learning rate is too high the gradient descent algorithm effectively runs backwards and tends to infinity and if it is lowered to the point where it actually converges towards a minima the number of iterations required to actually do so is unacceptably high.

Have I missed anything/made a mistake in the core algorithm?

Comment: Do you have a quick reference of your algorithm? That may be easier to locate the problem. Also, based on the intermediate result, the cost actually grows after each iteration, I think there must be something wrong.

Comment: The algorithm is taken from the Stanford machine learning course lecture [link](https://youtu.be/5u4G23_OohI), as well as a few other videos, thought it is pretty standard. The cost grows after each iteration only when the learning rate is too high (which I think is wrong), if the learning rate is lower it will *slowly* reduce.

Comment: Another thing is that I guess in the CostFunction() you need to take absolute value before you return.

Comment: I haven't watched the video from which you get the algorithm, but a gradient descent algorithm such as you describe inherently performs terribly.  The gradient approaches zero as you approach the minimum, which results in your algorithm slowing down as you approach the minimum.  Numerical Recipes has a reasonable discussion of minimization algorithms (which also isn't how you'd want to implement least squares if you care about efficiency, but I presume this is just a test case).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like everything is behaving as expected, but you are having problems selecting a reasonable learning rate. That's not a totally trivial problem, and there are many approaches ranging from pre-defined schedules that progressively reduce the learning rate (see e.g. [this paper](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98b.pdf)) to adaptive methods such as [AdaGrad](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume12/duchi11a/duchi11a.pdf) or AdaDelta.

For your vanilla implementation with fixed learning rate you should make your life easier by normalising the data to zero mean and unit standard deviation before you feed it into the gradient descent algorithm. That way you will be able to reason about the learning rate more easily. Then you can just rescale your prediction accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! Normalising the variables worked really well, I experimented around with different learning rates and iterations and it works exactly I would expect.